# Used to be able to ALT click to select bone but it seemed to turned off (I never change any setting)

Tags: armature, weight-painting, settings

Video reference: https://cloudmails-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/tp053611_mail_apu_edu_my/EUGJ5QR3jRpDvwUKUN7yY08BkuCVWl4Bbe4VcDRodZoY8A?nav=eyJyZWZlcnJhbEluZm8iOnsicmVmZXJyYWxBcHAiOiJPbmVEcml2ZUZvckJ1c2luZXNzIiwicmVmZXJyYWxBcHBQbGF0Zm9ybSI6IldlYiIsInJlZmVycmFsTW9kZSI6InZpZXciLCJyZWZlcnJhbFZpZXciOiJNeUZpbGVzTGlua0NvcHkifX0&e=gKr33E

Is there any solution?

Comment: Once you've parented, select the armature in Object mode, shift select the body, switch to Weight Paint mode, Ctrl left click on the bone you want?

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 4.0 some keys for weight painting have been changed.

- Select the bone —  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  or  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>
- Add a bone to selection —  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>
- smooth the weights —  <kbd>Shift</kbd>
- paint with opposite color —  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

There is a [video](https://youtu.be/sB8jHyDHpmE?si=FlbnepRbIye19xgZ) that explains it, it's 1 minute long.